# sort by number of occurrence(count) in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am new to Jquery and Javascript. Can someone please help me with Jquery sorting based on number of occurrence(count) in array. I tried various sorting methods but none of them worked.

I have an array in Javascript which is

```
allTypesArray = ["4", "4","2", "2", "2", "6", "2", "6", "6"]

// here  2 is printed four times, 6 is printed thrice, and 4 is printed twice
```

I need output like this

```
newTypesArray = ["2","6","4"]
```

I tried

```
function array_count_values(e) {
var t = {}, n = "",
    r = "";
var i = function (e) {
    var t = typeof e;
    t = t.toLowerCase();
    if (t === "object") {
        t = "array"
    }
    return t
};
var s = function (e) {
    switch (typeof e) {
    case "number":
        if (Math.floor(e) !== e) {
            return
        };
    case "string":
        if (e in this && this.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            ++this[e]
        } else {
            this[e] = 1
        }
    }
};
r = i(e);
if (r === "array") {
    for (n in e) {
        if (e.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
            s.call(t, e[n])
        }
    }
}
return t
}
6: 3
}
```

output is 
`{4: 2, 2: 6, 6:3}`

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: What were these various methods? How did they not work?

Comment: I hope the below post might help you to achieve the same..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464440/jquery-javascript-sort-array-by-highest-count

Comment: That is not sorting (*since you change the contents of the array*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, Yes it's sorting by occurrence count for each element.

Comment: @MaveRick that is grouping and sorting. Sorting just rearranges the array ..

Comment: Do you want jQuery or JS?  It looks like you should remove all mention of jQuery from this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just adding my idea as well (*a bit too late*)

```js
var allTypesArray = ["4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "6", "2", "6", "6"];
var map = allTypesArray.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

var newTypesArray = Object.keys(map).sort(function(a, b) {
  return map[b] - map[a];
});

console.log(newTypesArray)
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there's a direct solution in one step and of course it's not just a sort (a sort doesn't remove elements). A way to do this would be to build an intermediary map of objects to store the counts :

```
var allTypesArray = ["4", "4","2", "2", "2", "6", "2", "6", "6"];
var s = allTypesArray.reduce(function(m,v){
  m[v] = (m[v]||0)+1; return m;
}, {}); // builds {2: 4, 4: 2, 6: 3} 
var a = [];
for (k in s) a.push({k:k,n:s[k]});
// now we have [{"k":"2","n":4},{"k":"4","n":2},{"k":"6","n":3}] 
a.sort(function(a,b){ return b.n-a.n });
a = a.map(function(a) { return a.k });
```

Note that you don't need jQuery here. When you don't manipulate the DOM, you rarely need it.

Comment: FWIW you could save a couple chars `return m[v] = ++m[v]||0, m`

Comment: @elclanrs did it look like I was trying to golf ? ^^

Answer (score 2):

I don't think jquery is needed here.

There are several great answers to this question already, but I have found reliability to be an issue in some browsers (namely Safari 10 -- though there could be others).

A somewhat ugly, but seemingly reliable, way to solve this is as follows:

```
function uniqueCountPreserve(inputArray){
    //Sorts the input array by the number of time
    //each element appears (largest to smallest)

    //Count the number of times each item
    //in the array occurs and save the counts to an object
    var arrayItemCounts = {};
    for (var i in inputArray){
        if (!(arrayItemCounts.hasOwnProperty(inputArray[i]))){
            arrayItemCounts[inputArray[i]] = 1
        } else {
            arrayItemCounts[inputArray[i]] += 1
        }
    }

    //Sort the keys by value (smallest to largest)
    //please see Markus R's answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794116/4898004
    var keysByCount = Object.keys(arrayItemCounts).sort(function(a, b){
        return arrayItemCounts[a]-arrayItemCounts[b];
    });

    //Reverse the Array and Return
    return(keysByCount.reverse())
}
```

---

Test

```
uniqueCountPreserve(allTypesArray)
//["2", "6", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function i use to do this kind of stuff:

```
function orderArr(obj){
    const tagsArr = Object.keys(obj)
    const countArr = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b)=> b-a)
  const orderedArr = []
  countArr.forEach((count)=>{
    tagsArr.forEach((tag)=>{
        if(obj[tag] == count && !orderedArr.includes(tag)){
        orderedArr.push(tag)
      }
    })
  })
  return orderedArr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const allTypesArray = ["4", "4","2", "2", "2", "6", "2", "6", "6"]

const singles = [...new Set(allTypesArray)]
const sortedSingles = singles.sort((a,b) => a - b)
console.log(sortedSingles)
```

`Set` objects are collections of values. A value in the `Set` may only occur once; it is unique in the `Set`'s collection.

The `singles` variable spreads all of the unique values from `allTypesArray` using the `Set` object with the spread operator inside of an array.

The `sortedSingles` variable sorts the values of the `singles` array in ascending order by comparing the numbers.

Comment: the OP wants to sort based on the number each value appears in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's enough neat answers here, this is what I came up with:

Fill an object with counts for each of the elements:

```
let array = ['4', '4', '2', '2', '2', '6', '2', '6', '6'];
let arrayCounts = {}

for (j in array) arrayCounts[array[j]] ? arrayCounts[array[j]].count++ : arrayCounts[array[j]] = { val: array[j], count: 1 };

/* arrayCounts = {
  '2': { val: '2', count: 4 },
  '6': { val: '4', count: 2 },
  '4': { val: '6', count: 3 }
} */
```

For the values in that new object, sort them by .count, and map() them into a new array (with just the values):

```
let sortedArray = Object.values(arrayCounts).sort(function(a,b) { return b.count - a.count }).map(({ val }) => val);

/* sortedArray = [ '2', '6', '4' ] */
```

Altogether:

```
let arrayCounts = {}

for (j in array) arrayCounts[array[j]] ? arrayCounts[array[j]].count++ : arrayCounts[array[j]] = { val: array[j], count: 1 };
    
let sortedArray = Object.values(arrayCounts)
    .sort(function(a,b) { return b.count - a.count })
    .map(({ val }); => val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = [22,44,55,11,33,99,77,88];

for (var i = 0;i<number.length;i++) {
  for (var j=0;j<number.length;j++){
    if (number[j]>number[j+1]) {
      var primary = number[j];
      number[j] =  number[j+1];
      number[j+1] = primary;
    }
  }
}
document.write(number);
```

Comment: Here are sorting an Array using 2 loops.  First One is for showing output and the second one is for comparing values between arrays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.