# javascript custom sorting function to place lower occurrence first

Tags: javascript, sorting

Need to create a custom sort for an array --

-- first separate numbers by frequency
--- subset numbers of having frequency 1
--- subset numbers of having frequency 2

partially sorted data - with respect to asc order of frequency
- then we sort each subset of elements of having the same frequencey in non desc order

```
function cSort(arr) {
    if(typeof arr !== "undefined") {
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a - b;
        });

        return arr
    }
}
```

needs to satisfy the test cases

-- test 1
input
[5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4]
output
[1, 3, 4, 2, 2]

-- test 2
input
[10, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4] 
output 
[8, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]

--
current jsfiddle 1
http://jsfiddle.net/6mekdn8h/

new fiddle 2
http://jsfiddle.net/6mekdn8h/1/

Comment: needs to return by sorted frequence

Comment: What about `5`, I believe the output should be `[1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2]` isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort by number of occurrence(count) in Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010520/sort-by-number-of-occurrencecount-in-javascript-array)

Comment: not sure why 5 is opted out -- but its not in the test result expected

Comment: @Scath -- tried it -- didn't pass the tests --

Comment: [5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4] --- should be output [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]

Comment: [10, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4] -- should output [8, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a sorting with the count of the occurences of each item.

```js
var array = [5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4].slice(1),
    hash = array.reduce((h, v, i) => (h[v] = (h[v] || 0) + 1, h), {});

array.sort((a, b) => hash[a] - hash[b] || a - b);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6mekdn8h/2/  test 2 input [10, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4] output [8, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]

Comment: you could take only the rest without the first element.

Comment: whats the solution?

Comment: so this is coming out at  [8, 10, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]  -- instead of  [8, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]

Comment: you could splice the larget item.

Comment: there is no 10 in the input my mistake

Comment: the old is back.